# Android Jetpack Recursive Navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm trying out Android Sunflower App. I've requirement to show a list of topics. When a topic is clicked, I want to show sub topics, recursively. I tried to model this around the Plant List view in Android sunflower.

What is the best way to handle this kind of recursion? I have two ideas in mind.

1. On topic item's click handler, update the viewmodel with a parent topic id, and let the ui update while remaining in the same fragment. In this approach, how can I support back button properly? How to access the list's view model from the list item's click listener?
2. Open a new fragment with the correct navigation arguments. In this approach, how do setup the navigation such that the new fragment only replaces the fragment that holds the list. When I tried this approach, it was replacing the whole tab layout of the Sunflower app.

Please help.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Stuck here, bump thread.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem.
Now I've found a solution by utilizing both navArgs & viewModel.

**PlantListFragment.kt**

```
class PlantListFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel by inject<PlantListViewModel>()
    private val args by navArgs<PlantListFragmentArgs>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         // Pass nav arg (list) to view model to initialize.
         // Assuming you already setup the argument in the navigation file properly.
         viewModel.setupFromNavArgs(args.list)
    }

    fun setupList() {
         viewModel.list.observe(viewLifeCycleOwner) {
             // Do the list view setup with `it`
         }
    }
}
```

**PlantListViewModel.kt**

```
class PlantListViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _list = MutableLiveData<List<Plant>>()
    val list: LiveData<List<Plant>> = _list
    fun setupFromNavArgs(list: List<Plant>) {
        if (_list.value == null) {
             _list.value = list
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck!